# In ctags how do I add unique names to markdown headings?

Tags: vim, markdown, ctags

I'm using universal tags. I have several markdown files that start with # Introduction # Getting started. To avoid
duplicate tags I started doing `# Topic1 Introduction` and `# Topic2 Introduction`. This
does not look good in documentation, is there a way that I can make unique tags based on file name
without changing the markdown?

What I want to do in vim is:

```
:tag topic1 introduction
```

But I want the markdown to look like this:

```markdown
## Introduction

Something about topic1.
```

I don't want to create my own language file but if I have to I can do something like `touch ~/.ctags.d/mymarkdown.ctags` ? I'm not experienced in ctags, this was just something I was messing around with before the markdown default file was patched.

```sh
--_mtable-regex-MarkdownNew=main_sharp/^##[ \t]+([^\n]+)([ \t]+#+)[\n]*/\1/s/{_field=sectionMarker:##}{scope=push}{tenter=section,main}
```

Do something like this:

```sh
...*/printf "%s%s" \1 this.filename/s/{_file=...
```

I understand that this may be difficult because the tags need to get referenced some how.

So my next question to that would be, is there a way I can associate file1.md line 11 with 'topic1 introduction' tag in the .tags file? Then I would associate file2.md line 9 with 'topic2 introduction' in the .tags file. Then I could just reference `:tag topic1 introduction` and `:tag topic2 introduction`

Comment: If there is no mention of `topic1` in the file, how do you expect ctags to pick it up?

Comment: @romainl You're right so my next question to that would be, is there a way I can associate file1.md line 11 with 'topic1 introduction' tag in the .tags file? Then I would associate file2.md line 9 with 'topic2 introduction' in the .tags file. Then I could just reference ```:tag topic1 introduction``` and ```:tag topic2 introduction```

Comment: If you have one `## Introduction` per file and you can tell which one you want by the filename, you could use `:tselect Introduction` which will show you a menu with each tag matching "Introduction" and their filenames, so you can pick the one you'd like to jump to...

Answer (score 2):

If "topic" == "file", then you can simply use `:tjump Introduction` (I did `:tj /intro`, here) and choose the tag you want:

[image: :tjump]

The problem with this, however, is that it obviously doesn't scale beyond a few files/topics. But, if we are honest with ourselves, a system built on memorising topics/filenames like you are suggesting is probably even less scaleable.

If you *really* want that API:

```
:<command> <topic> <tag>
```

then the most interesting approach might be to create a custom command that behaves a bit like `:help :cscope`, with "sub-command"-like completion:

```
:Foo <Tab>
(completes from available topics)
:Foo topic1 <Tab>
(completes from available tags for chosen topic)
:Foo topic1 Introduction<CR>
(opens the given tag)
```

Here are pointers that may prove useful if you want to go that route:

```
:help taglist()
:help filter()
:help :command-completion
:help :command-completion-customlist
```

Comment: I think you're suggesting I find a work around like creating a vim function to handle it. As far as scaling, it's easy to remember tags by file name (e.g., :tag git introduction, :tag lua introduction, :tag go introduction, :tag web introduction, :tag css introduction) .........

Comment: It may be easy with a few topics/files. But I have a directory of notes, here that goes back to the early 00's with hundreds of files and dozens and dozens of topics. Remembering so many filenames/topics is, I think, impossible for most humans so I am pretty sure such a system would not work beyond a certain limit. In any case, yes, I am more than suggesting that you write a custom command that does what you want because the solution you imagined is impractical.

Comment: Yea, in your case having lots of files tied in to one tags file can get tricky I agree. You should try [FZF Vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) the ```:Tags Topic``` command works great for those situations.

Comment: No thanks, I am not the one with a problem, here.